# HTML Float issue - should be simple but can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to left align a div within a div that has been center aligned with  margin: 0px auto; but i just can't seem to get it working, i know this is a simple issue but i just can't seem to get it to work...

any help would be brill !

PS - i have attached an image of the problem, just can see the left col is float-left but now the background (seen on the right) is creeping up...

[alt text http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1778/screenshot20091021at125.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1778/screenshot20091021at125.png)

```
#wrap {
width: 940px; 
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: left;
background-color: #c3c1c1;
}

nav {
width: 220px;
height: auto;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: I recommend that you make the title of your question a little more descriptive to your problem so that others with the same issue may have the opportunity to find an answer as well

Comment: sorry here is my code:

#wrap {
 width: 940px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #c3c1c1;
}

nav {
 width: 220px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**float:left** should do the trick

**EDIT:** You can put all your text in another div that is **float:left** make sure to set the width properly though

Comment: think that has solved the issue now, seems a bit unnecessary to add another div but if it works the payoff is worth it :)

Answer (score 1):

For your outer `div`, try `text-align:left;`
and for your inner `div`, try possibly `float:left;`.

Others will post nicer, cleaner answers, but this will get you started.

Comment: Hi i did try that initially and it does work but it cuts off the background of the outer div, like it is breaking the outer div somehow

Comment: could you post your code then so we can get a better grasp of what you are trying to do